# How to fix NavLink issue(NavLink does not toggle active class)?

Tags: react-router

I have problem with NavLink component. It works fine, but it does not toggle the active class or any other.

I tried to use activeClassName or activeStyle but it still doesn't work. I have tried solutions, which I found on github or stackoverflow but none of these solved my problem. I've got react ^16.8.6, react dom ^16.8.6, react router ^5.0.1, react router dom ^5.0.1 and react scripts 3.0.1

'''

```js
<header>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <NavLink activeClassName="active" to="/" exact >Start</NavLink>
              </li>
              <li>
                <NavLink activeClassName="active" to="/news" >News</NavLink>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </header>
```

```css
.active {
  border-bottom-color: yellow;
}
```

I expected NavLink to toggle this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that implements "selected" class when the link is active else "normal" class is implemented

```
import React from "react"
import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom"
import "./Components/style.css"


class Navbar extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><NavLink exact to = "/" activeClassName="selected" className="normal"><h3>Start</h3></NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink exact to = "/mid" activeClassName="selected" className="normal"><h3>Mid</h3></NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink exact to = "/end" activeClassName="selected" className="normal"><h3>End</h3></NavLink></li>



                </ul>   
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Navbar
```

And my stylesheet is

```
.normal{
    border: 2px solid green;
}
.selected{
    border: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

Comment: className="normal" works, but class selected is still not added :/